# Vue / Vuetify - Display v-select text value in a <span>

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How do I display the text of a `v-select` in a `<span>`? I'm trying to create a printable report and I can't pull-out all the `item-text` value. I also have multiple `v-select` using `array.push`

```
   <span>{{ insert item-text }}</span>

<v-select
 v-model="value"
 :items="data"
 item-text="data_name" 
 item-value="id"
/>

export default {
 data() {
  return {
  data: [],
  value: [],
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, selected item is stored in `value` because that is what you specified in `v-model`:

```html
<span>{{ selected }}</span>

<v-select
 v-model="value"
 :items="data"
 item-text="data_name" 
 item-value="id"
/>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  data: [
    {id: 0, data_name:'Apples'},
    {id: 1, data_name:'Apricots'},
    {id: 2, data_name:'Avocado'},
    {id: 3, data_name:'Bananas'}
  ],
  value: null,
}),
computed: {
  selected () {
    return this.data.find(item => item.id === this.value) 
  }
}
```

Since you specified `item-value="id"` you are getting the `id`. If you only need `data_name` you can specify `item-value="data_name"` to begin with. And then you have the text stored in the `value` without doing anything:

```js
<span>{{ value }}</span>

<v-select
  v-model="value"
  :items="data"
  item-text="data_name" 
  item-value="data_name"
/>
```